# What is the range of Deflect Missiles?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk

When a monk uses Deflect Missiles and reduces the damage to 0 he/she can spend a Ki point to throw it back. But what is the range he can throw the missile/weapon back at? Is it the range of the weapon that fired it?

Answer (score 24):

**20/60** feet from Player's Handbook [errata](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/Errata_PH.pdf)